# Bubble Sort in NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm

I wrote a program of bubble sort in NASM. But it shows segmentation fault. I tried to generate assembly version of the following c code:

```
    for(k=0;k<n;k++){
       ptr=0;
       while(ptr<=n-k){

          if(data[ptr]>data[ptr+1])
             do swap
          ptr++;  
       }
     }
```

The following NASM code is:

```
    section .data
      msg db "%d"
      four dd 4
      msga db "%d ",0

    section .bss
      arr resd 8

    section .text
      global main
      extern printf,scanf
    main:
      xor ecx,ecx
    lp:
      mov ebx,arr     ;; from this line to jnz lp is using for taking 8 inputs
      mov eax,ecx
      mul dword[four]
      add ebx,eax
      pusha

      push ebx
      push msg
      call scanf
      add esp,8
      popa

      inc ecx
      cmp ecx,8
      jnz lp

      mov ecx,0   ;; sorting replication of the above c program is starting
      mov ebx,7   ;; outerloop will execute from 0 to 7
    outerLoop:  
      mov eax,0   ;; it sets ptr=0
    .innerLoop:
      mov edx,8
      sub edx,ecx
      cmp eax,edx  ;; its using for cheking ptr<=n-k

      push ebx
      push ecx
      push edx
      add esp,12

      jle .task
      pop edx
      pop ecx
      pop ebx
      inc ecx

      cmp ecx, ebx ;; its using for cheking whether k is in between 0 to 7
      jl outerLoop

      xor ecx,ecx
      jmp lp1
  .task:
      mov ebx,dword[arr+eax*4]   ;; its using to get data[ptr]
      mov ecx,eax
      push eax
      add esp,4

      add ecx,1
      mov edx,dword[arr+ecx*4]   ;; its using to get data[ptr+1]

      cmp ebx,edx
      jl .activity
      xchg ebx,edx
      mov dword[arr+eax*4],ebx
      mov dword[arr+ecx*4],edx
 .activity:
     pop eax
     pop edx
     pop ecx
     pop ebx

     inc eax
     jmp .innerLoop

 lp1:                 ;; its using for print the output
   mov ebx,arr
   mov eax,ecx

   mul dword[four]
   add ebx,eax
   pusha

   push dword[ebx]
   push msga
   call printf
   add esp,8
   popa
   inc ecx
   cmp ecx,8
   jne lp1
```

Will u pls help me to find out my mistake?
thanx in advance

Comment: My suggestion would be run it in a debugger, to see where it segfaults and what the state of the program is at that point.

Comment: @NPE: I ran it in a debugger. it shows smethng junk value in ebx,edx aftr exchg cmmand apperas. and then the sef fault occurs

Comment: unbalanced stack, nothing more to say

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do a Bubble sort?  Start with something easier.  Walk before you run.

Look at the inner loop, you have:

```
  push ebx
  push ecx
  push edx
  add esp,12

  jle .task
```

You push those 3 registers onto to the stack and immediately remove them (you didn't even pop them back into their respective registers, so not only is your stack not balanced, your registers contain the wrong values).  Now that you "cleaned up the stack" with `add esp, 12`, anytime you have your `pop`s, the stack is wrong.

Comment: I push those registers to store their earlier values.And i re assign new values in the .task section. They have been popped at the .activity section. Pls, dont take it otherway, I cant get what you want to say. It will be useful for me.....if you tell me how to solve the mistake.

Comment: You do the same thing that Gunner spotted (Hi Gunner!) in another place: `push eax`/`add esp, 4`. Get rid of that one too, and your program completes. Result isn't quite right, but you're closin' in on it!

Comment: @Frank - Good to see you around here also!  @Saugata - There is no hand holding in Assembly, just about anything will fly and the Assembler won't tell you about it as long as the instructions are valid.  You have to keep an eye on the stack, you must pair your `pushes` with the `pop`s this is more important when you are jumping around like you are.  Ok, you push the registers thinking you are saving the values but you are not.

Comment: @Gunner,@Frank: thanx for ur valuable advice.I am trying